# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') in my click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function connected to the click of a button, but it gives me this problem, how could I solve it?

```
function ClickHelp() {
        if ($("#text_help").html()=="" || $("#text_help").html().indexOf("non presente per il")>0){
            if ($("#frameapplication").length>0)
            var titolo2=document.getElementById("frameapplication").contentWindow.location.href.replace(".html","").split("/");
            var url = '';
            var nomecompleto = '';
            if (titolo2.length > 0) url = titolo2[titolo2.length - 1];
                nomecompleto = "/htdocs/" + url.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + "_help.html";
                $("#text_help").load(nomecompleto);

    }
}
```

```
<div class="help-container" id="help-container" onclick="ClickHelp()">
<button class="menu" id="sized" onclick="document.getElementById('help').style.display='block'">
<i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="help">
<div class="modal-content_menu animated fadeInRight">
<div class="w3-container">
<div class="modal-header_menu">
<span class="close"onclick="document.getElementById('help').style.display='none'">×</span>
<div id="text_help" class="modal-body_menu"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML layout of your `#text_help` element.

Comment: yes, I just posted it

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that *demonstrates* the issue - your code, as provided, does not give an error on `$("#text_help").html().indexOf` https://jsfiddle.net/wvhpzLxj/  it does give other errors later on, but not the error you've described.   My guess would be that either the `.modal#help` doesn't exist at the time your code runs or it's been remove()'d (at the time your code runs).  Check if `#text_help` exists as you *already do* with frameapplication.

Comment: It's because '#frameapplication" does not exist on the page

Comment: Frameapplication is in a div `<div class="container_frame"><iframe id="frameapplication" name="frameapplication" scrolling="no" src="sem_menu2.html" style="width: 100%;height:800px;border:0px" onload="$('#help').html('')" ></iframe>
</div>`